# Installing Mysql2 gem Windows 8 ( already followed solutions )

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

i have as a lot of people an issue while trying to install mysql2 gem on windows 8.

I have followed a lot of post to fix it but it's still here .

I have already done :

_ Download ruby 1.9.3

_ Install Devkit

_ Put both ruby and devkit in environment variables path

_ DL mysql-connector and svm-map

_ Copy libmysql.dll into ruby folder

and when i run this command :

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:/mysql-connector/"'
```

I have this :

```
http://gyazo.com/2b0f78b04fcb9d13e40889ffbd895381
http://gyazo.com/890053ff296a0dc69687bbcd830fbc7a
http://gyazo.com/4e7b04a9f8e6d99efdbb1ff130487f51
```

Thank you if you can help me :D

Answer (score 0):

When I started working with Rails on Windows I used Bitnami RubyStack. Try it, maybe you will like it too.